# How to get redirect log in Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, redirect, mechanize

In ruby, if you use mechanize following 301/302 redirects like this

```
require 'mechanize'

m = WWW::Mechanize.new
m.get('http://google.com')
```

how to get the list of the pages mechanize was redirected through? (Like http://google.com => http://www.google.com => http://google.com.ua)

OK, here is the code in mechanize responsible for redirection

```
 elsif res_klass <= Net::HTTPRedirection
        return page unless follow_redirect?
        log.info("follow redirect to: #{ response['Location'] }") if log
        from_uri  = page.uri
        raise RedirectLimitReachedError.new(page, redirects) if redirects + 1 > redirection_limit
        redirect_verb = options[:verb] == :head ? :head : :get
        page = fetch_page(  :uri => response['Location'].to_s,
                            :referer => page,
                            :params  => [],
                            :verb => redirect_verb,
                            :redirects => redirects + 1
                         )
        @history.push(page, from_uri)
        return page
```

but trying to m.history.map {|p| puts p.uri} shows 3 times the uri of last page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain, but here are a couple of things to try:

1. see what's in `m.history[i].uri` after the get()
2. You might need something like:

```
    for m.redirection_limit in 0..99
      begin
        m.get(url)
        break
        rescue WWW::Mechanize::RedirectLimitReachedError
          # code here could get control at
          # intermediate redirection levels
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

The key here is to take advantage of the built in logging in Mechanize.  Here's a full code sample using the built in Rails logging facilities.

> require 'mechanize'
>
> require 'logger'
>
> mechanize_logger = Logger.new('log/mechanize.log')
>
> mechanize_logger.level = Logger::INFO
>
> url = 'http://google.com'
>
> agent = Mechanize.new
>
> agent.log = mechanize_logger
>
> agent.get(url)

And then check the output of log/mechanize.log in your log directory and you'll see the whole mechanize process including the intermediate urls.