# Use Mechanize (Python) to get redirection log

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I want to get the url redirection log using Mechanize written in Python. For example, www.google.com --> www.google.co.in. The exact question has been asked before in SO but it is for Ruby

[How to get redirect log in Mechanize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352178/how-to-get-redirect-log-in-mechanize)

The answer explains that to do this one can do the following in Ruby -

```
for m.redirection_limit in 0..99
  begin
    m.get(url)
    break
    rescue WWW::Mechanize::RedirectLimitReachedError
      # code here could get control at
      # intermediate redirection levels
  end
end
```

I want to do the same using Python. Any help? What is the alternate of get(url) in Python for Mechanize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `HTTPRedirectHandler.redirect_request()` method to save a redirection history:

```
import urllib2

class HTTPRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers, newurl):
        newreq = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.redirect_request(self,
            req, fp, code, msg, headers, newurl)
        if newreq is not None:
            self.redirections.append(newreq.get_full_url())
        return newreq

url = 'http://google.com'

h = HTTPRedirectHandler()
h.max_redirections = 100
h.redirections = [url]
opener = urllib2.build_opener(h)
response = opener.open(url)
print h.redirections
# -> ['http://google.com', 'http://www.google.com/', 'http://google.com.ua/']
```

It should be much faster than the provided `WWW::Mechanize` code snippet because `urllib2` visits each url only once.

`mechanize` provides a superset of `urllib2` functionality i.e., if you use `mechanize` then just replace every occurrence of `urllib2` above with `mechanize` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to give you an 'IGIFY', but you are right, mechanize documentation sucks.  Poking around a bit, it looks like you should look at urllib2, as mechanize exposes that entire interface.

Comment: using urllib2 wouldn't help since I want to simulate browser behavior using mechanize.

Comment: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/documentation.html They explicitly say look at the urllib2 documentation multiple times on that page.

Answer (score 1):

j.f sebastian's answer works great if they are http redirections, but this would fail if they were javascript redirections. (urllib2 doesnt handle javascript redirections but Mechanize does!)

this should work for both types of redirections though!

```
import mechanize
import logging
import sys
logger = logging.getLogger("mechanize")
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_debug_redirects(True)

r=browser.open("http://google.com")
```